# Java Graphics clear arc

Tags: java, graphics, draw, paintcomponent

Is there a method like clearRect(), but clearArc() ?
I want to fill all the screen except one circle, something like that: [image: picture (without those rounded corners)]
( I'm doing that in paintComponent() )

P.S. Background is transparent

Comment: Get the default color and then fillArc()?

Comment: No, I have transparent background

Comment: Did you try using a transparent Color (ie. `new Color(0, 0, 0, 0)`) with the fillArc()?

Comment: I think, this won't work(

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Try it out:

```
import java.awt.Graphics2D;
import java.awt.geom.Area;
import java.awt.geom.Ellipse2D;
import java.awt.geom.RoundRectangle2D;
// and other stuffes you should have already imported

@Override
public void paintComponent(Graphics g) {
    super.paintComponent(g);
    Area area = new Area(
            new RoundRectangle2D.Double(0, 0, 200, 200, 50, 50));
    area.subtract(new Area(new Ellipse2D.Double(75, 50, 50, 50)));
    g.setColor(Color.RED);
    ((Graphics2D) g).fill(area);
}
```

Link to Java Tutorial: http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/2d/ (I'm somewhat lazy now...)

[image]